# mbstring (php/phalcon) - installed but not appearing in phpinfo()

Tags: apache2, php

I tried to install mbstring to use Phalcon, I don't know what I'm doing wrong but it doesn't appear in phpinfo().

Here's is basically what I've used :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install php ; 8.2 here
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
```

After that I edited the file **/etc/php/8.2/apache2/php.ini** (note that this is the one that appear in the "Loaded Configuration File" when using phpinfo()) to modify from :

```
; extension=mbstring
```

to

```
extension=mbstring
```

extension_dir is still commented.
Also tried that :

```
extension=/usr/lib/php/20210902/mbstring.so
```

As **find / -type f -name "mbstring.so"** returns /usr/lib/php/20210902/mbstring.so

Then

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Once done there is still nothing about mbstring using phpinfo().

What I am doing wrong ?

I'm pretty sure this is only one step I missed. FYI :

```
root@localhost:/etc/php/8.2/mods-available# php -m | grep mbstring
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mbstring.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20220829/mbstring.so (/usr/lib/php/20220829/mbstring.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20220829/mbstring.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20220829/mbstring.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

**EDIT : Got the same issue for phalcon.so and php-xml so I really think I missed something...**

**EDIT2 : I'm trying to do the thing as they must be done, so don't hesitate to told me if something seems wrong.**

Comment: You may be doing something very wrong but can not know for sure as you did not give the version of Ubuntu you are using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: If you have installed Python 8.2 on a Ubuntu 22.04 OS machine you not longer have a working OS. Ubuntu needs the version of Python it ships with, the exact version. If you change the default a lot of the OS functions will no longer work. The wisest thing to do is a fresh new install of the OS and then learn about setting up multiple Python version on the OS and not replacing the default. Ubuntu 22.04 default is Python 10.

Comment: I think there is a missunderstand here. I didn't touch Python, only PHP.

Comment: Great and yes I read that but a common next step is to mess with Python I should have made it clear it was a warning.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 has PHP 8.1 in the default repositories. Which source repos are you using for 8.2? Ondrej or something else? All of my projects use `mbstring` and I haven't had to mess around with `php.ini` for any system in years ...

Comment: @matigo You're right ! Tried from 0 again and got PHP8.1 so I do think I was using Ondrej's repository as I wanted to use it to get PHP7.4. Still, used "apt-get install php-mbstring" but now I have doubt on how to link it to apache, as the mbstring section still missing. When I used "phpenmod mbstring" it worked ! Finally.